# MySQL Selecting records by multiple IDs with LIMIT per each ID

Tags: php, arrays, select, mysqli

I'm stuck with my MySQLi query. The scenario is like this:
  - I need to select max 10 comments for each post.
  - I'm using this query but it doesn't work the way I need
  - Post IDs are in array

```
$comments_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE pid IN ({$decodedPostIds}) AND state='1' order by time LIMIT 10");
```

- LIMIT 10 applies for comments as whole.

Thanks in advance for all advices and answers.
Ps. I'm sorry for my english.
Peter

Comment: What is it currently returning?

Comment: only 10 comments but not per each post but for entire query (for all posts)

Comment: Without seeing your database, it's hard to guess... but your query looks ok to me. Are you sure that `$decodedPostIds` is properly formatted and contains the proper post ids?

Comment: yep, it works properly without LIMIT 10

Comment: db looks like this:
Table comments                                            
comment_id    |    post_to_which_it_belongs_to_id    |   time

Comment: What do you mean it works properly without the `LIMIT 10` ? That should not make any difference in the results. All it does is limit your result set to 10 records

Comment: for example:
we have post1 that has 100 comments,   post2 has 50 comments and post3 has 25 comments..... i want to load 10 comments for post1, 10 comments for post2  and 10 comments for post3 but it loads 10 comments for post1 and no comments for post2 and post3

Comment: You desired results could be accomplished with a more complex query with sub-queries, but the easiest thing would just be to run the query you have 1 time per post id.

Comment: This may help http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-max-function/ `SELECT MAX(column)` and maybe use an alias. I.e.: `SELECT MAX(column) as whatever`

Comment: @Fred -ii- thanks but I have already resolved the problem by executing query for each post ID as mituw16 suggested.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it was resolved. *Cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LIMIT 10
```

says that the result will contain 10 lines from the HOLE query output.

Lets say in database you have 2 posts: post1 contain 5 related comments, and post2 contain 10 related comments.

executing the query: 
`SELECT * FROM comments WHERE pid IN ({$decodedPostIds}) AND state='1' order by time`

will return:

- post1: comment1
- post1: comment2
- post1: comment3
- post1: comment4
- post1: comment5
- post2: comment1
- post2: comment2
- post2: comment3
- post2: comment4
- post2: comment5
- post2: comment6
- post2: comment7
- post2: comment8
- post2: comment9
- post2: comment10

Now, adding `LIMIT 10` to query, will return the FIRST 10 lines of the hole result, meaning from *post1: comment1* to *post2: comment5*

You have 2 solutions:

1. make a loop for each post and execute your query on that post:

   SELECT * FROM comments WHERE pid = **$post_id** AND state='1' order by time LIMIT 10
2. fetch ALL posts and, using PHP code, group the first 10'th comments of each post

pseudo code:

```
$rows = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT * FROM comments WHERE WHERE pid IN ({$decodedPostIds}) AND state='1' order by time LIMIT 10');

foreach($rows as $row){
    if(count($arr[$row['post_id']]) < 10){
        array_push($arr[$row['post_id']],$row)
    }
}
```

now $arr is array where each key is post_id with it 10'th comments as value.

IMO: I prefer solution 2(hate to execute queries in loop).

Hope it help a bit.